# Why did John Brittle have Bible pages sewed into his shirt?

Tags: analysis, django-unchained

In *Django Unchained*, Django approaches "Big John" Brittle as he's about to whip a young black slave woman.  As Django approaches, we see that John has some Bible pages sewed into his shirt, and is reciting Bible passages.  The Bible pages aren't remarked upon by any of the characters in the scene, but it seems pretty odd to me.

Why did John Brittle have Bible pages sewed into his shirt?

Answer (score 11):

I haven't found any interviews with Tarantino or the rest of the crew to definitively answer this, but I think it's largely about the symbolism involved.

Just before Django killed John Brittle, he is recited scripture from the Old Testament (about justice) to a slave girl, while he whips her. He believes he is right. He believes he is superior to the girl, from a superior race. He treats her a lesser being and nothing more than that.

Django then challenges him and shoots him. His blood pours out of his wound which just so happens to be right in the middle of one of the bible pages. Considering the fact he was lecturing the girl on justice before his death, to me this suggests Tarantino was implying this was the real "justice" being delivered, with his blood appeasing the words of the Old Testament.

So in summary I think the Bible pages are there to demonstrate his belief that he is one of God's servants. I think they also serve a double purpose as his death and bleeding out on top of the scriptures symbolise "justice" being done given his false beliefs.

Comment: You're somewhat mistaken regarding "justice".  I'm not religious, but that part of the bible doesn't have anything to do with justice at all.  It's part of "The Covenant of the Rainbow", basically the second of 3 statements of what God says to Noah about man's relationship to the animals.  For example, it's concluded with `Everything that lives and moves will be food for you; just as I gave you the green plants, I now give you all things`.

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated That actually enforces the answer - John treats the slave girl as the "animal", as given to him by God.

Comment: @Yasskier, (?)  Sure, but what you are referring to is akin to a _hierarchy_ of creatures on Earth.  Andrew was saying that the passage had to do with _justice_.  Completely different.  The bible is talking about _**food sources**_, not some reference to "justice".  Andrew however said `he is recited scripture from the Old Testament (about justice)`.  That part of the bible isn't referring to justice at all.